# iOS Facebook LoginButton constraints conflict

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, autolayout

I want to resize facebook's `LoginButton`, but I am getting this error

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
>
> Try this:
>
> (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
>
> (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>
> (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
>
> (
>       "NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1c4283ed0 h=--& v=--& FBSDKLoginButton: 0x104432fd0'Log in'.height == 40   (active)",
>
> "NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c42828f0 FBSDKLoginButton:0x104432fd0'Log in'.height == 28   (active)>"
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c42828f0 FBSDKLoginButton:0x104432fd0'Log in'.height == 28   (active)>

I've searched a lot, and have no idea how `height == 28` constraint exists.

Creating `LoginButton`:

```
private var didLayoutSubviews = false {
    didSet {
        //I've use storyboard first, but couldn't make it work with resizing 
        self.facebookSignUpButton.removeFromSuperview()

        self.facebookSignUpButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [.email, .publicProfile])

        //I've tried to set `isActive = false`
        self.facebookSignUpButton.constraints.forEach({self.facebookSignUpButton.removeConstraint($0)})

        self.facebookSignUpButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(self.facebookSignUpButton)
        self.facebookSignUpButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.googleSignUpButton.frame.height - 8).isActive = true
        self.facebookSignUpButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.googleSignUpButton.frame.width - 8).isActive = true
        self.facebookSignUpButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.facebookSignUpButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.separatorLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        self.facebookSignUpButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.googleSignUpButton.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        self.facebookSignUpButton.delegate = self.presenter
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if !self.didLayoutSubviews {
        self.didLayoutSubviews = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The notification to developers is in the [Facebook Guidelines for 4.19](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4x#4180to4190) . This has already been [discussed on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002346/cannot-change-the-height-of-login-button-in-fbsdkloginkit).

Personally, I was only able to make this work with a custom login button in Swift 4.

Comment: I got it, but I am removing all constraints of this button first, and cannot understand, why they are not removed